# How to print the full path of Dijkstra’s algorithm in Java

Tags: java, graph-algorithm, dijkstra

Currently, only the final vertex is being printed, and the minimum distance seems to evaluate to infinity. I can't seem to find where the issue is with vertex's not being added to the "shortest path" ArrayList. I would like to also print out all the edges that are taken by the path. Any suggestions are very welcome Below is my full code, thanks!

**Edit**: I have edited my classes as recommended by sprinter.

An error is in my Graph class, in my getNeighbours() method. The information regarding the source is being added as a neighbor, even though I'm trying to get it's neighbors.

I am also not sure how to print out the edge info, along with the Vertex info.

Any recommendations are greatly appreciated!

**ShortestPathFinder**

```
class ShortestPathFinder {
        private  Graph graph = new Graph();
        private  Vertex source = new Vertex(0, null);
        private Vertex destination = new Vertex(0,null);
        private  Map<Vertex,Double> minimumWeightToVertices = new HashMap();
        private  Map<Vertex,Vertex> previousVertex = new HashMap();
        private  Set<Vertex> visited =  new HashSet();

        private  Map<Vertex,Double> neighbors = new HashMap();

    public Optional<Path> findShortestPath(Graph graph, Vertex source, Vertex destination) {
        this.graph = graph;
        this.source = graph.getVertex(source);
        this.destination = graph.getVertex(destination);
        Optional<Path> pathFound = Optional.empty();

        //start queue at source vertex
        source.setDistance(0);
        PriorityQueue<Vertex> priorityQueue = new PriorityQueue<>();
        priorityQueue.add(source);
        source.setVisited(true);

        while( !priorityQueue.isEmpty() ){
          // Getting the minimum distance vertex from priority queue
          Vertex actualVertex = priorityQueue.poll();   
          //get Neighbors of source vertex 
          neighbors = graph.getNeighbours(source);
        //find Neighbor with lowest weight
          for(Entry<Vertex, Double> neighbor : neighbors.entrySet()){             
                 Vertex v = neighbor.getKey();
                if(v == destination) {
                    minimumWeightToVertices.put(v,v.getDistance());
                    v.setPredecessor(actualVertex);
                    previousVertex.put(actualVertex,v);
                    priorityQueue.add(v);
                    // found, set pathFound = Optional.of(path) 
                    Path path = new Path();
                    pathFound = Optional.of(path);
                }
                else if(visited.contains(v) == false)
                {
                    double newDistance = actualVertex.getDistance() + neighbor.getValue();

                    //when found min add to minmumWeightToVertices
                    if( newDistance < v.getDistance() ){
                        priorityQueue.remove(v);
                        v.setDistance(newDistance);
                        minimumWeightToVertices.put(v,newDistance);
                        v.setPredecessor(actualVertex);
                        previousVertex.put(actualVertex,v);
                        priorityQueue.add(v);
                        System.out.println("Added: " + v.getID());
                    }
                }
            }
           //When visited add to visited so not visited again
            actualVertex.setVisited(true);
            visited.add(actualVertex);  
          //continue getting neighbors with lowest index until destination reached 
        }       
        return pathFound;       
    }

    public void getPath() {     
        //print all info using previous Vertex and print out edge info from it
        for (Entry<Vertex, Vertex> entry : previousVertex.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("ID: " + entry.getKey().getID() + " Name: " + entry.getKey().getName() +
                    " to  "  + "ID: " + entry.getValue().getID() + " Name: " + entry.getValue().getName());
        }
    }
}
```

***Graph***

```
class Graph {
    private final Set<Vertex> vertices = new HashSet<Vertex>();
    private final Set<Edge> edges = new HashSet<Edge>();


    public void addVertex(int id, String name) {
        Vertex vertex = new Vertex(id,name);
        vertices.add(vertex);
        //System.out.println("ID:" +  vertex.getID() + "Name:" + vertex.getName());
    }
    public void addEdge(double weight, Vertex vertex1, Vertex vertex2, String extra) {
        Edge edge = new Edge(weight,vertex1,vertex2,extra);
        edges.add(edge);        
    }
    public void printVertices() {
        for(Vertex vertex : vertices){
               System.out.println("ID:" + vertex.getID() + " Name:" + vertex.getName());
            }   
    }
    public void printEdges() {
        for(Edge edge : edges){
               System.out.println("StartVertex:" + edge.getStartVertex() +" EndVertex:" + edge.getTargetVertex()+ "Weight:" + edge.getWeight());
            }

    }
    public Vertex getVertex(Vertex v) {
        return v;
    }
     public Map<Vertex, Double> getNeighbours(Vertex vertex) {
         Map<Vertex,Double> neighbors = new HashMap();

         Object[] check = edges.toArray();

         for(int i = 0; i < edges.size(); i++) {
            if(((Edge) check[i]).getStartVertex().getID() == vertex.getID()) {
                neighbors.put(((Edge) check[i]).getTargetVertex(),((Edge) check[i]).getWeight());
            }
            else if(((Edge) check[i]).getTargetVertex().getID() == vertex.getID()) {
                neighbors.put(((Edge) check[i]).getStartVertex(),((Edge) check[i]).getWeight());
            }
         }
        return neighbors; 
     }
}
```

***Edge***

```
public class Edge {

    private double weight;
    private Vertex startVertex;
    private Vertex targetVertex;
    private String extra;

    public Edge(double weight, Vertex startVertex, Vertex targetVertex, String extra) {
        this.weight = weight;
        this.startVertex = startVertex;
        this.targetVertex = targetVertex;
        this.extra = extra;
    }

    public double getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    public void setWeight(double weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public Vertex getStartVertex() {
        return startVertex;
    }

    public void setStartVertex (Vertex startVertex) {
        this.startVertex = startVertex;
    }

    public Vertex getTargetVertex() {
        return targetVertex;
    }

    public void setTargetVertex(Vertex targetVertex) {
        this.targetVertex = targetVertex;
    }
    public String getExtra() {
        return extra;
    }
    public void setExtra(String extra) {
        this.extra = extra;
    }
}
```

***Vertex***

```
public class Vertex implements Comparable<Vertex> {

    private int ID;
    private String name;
    private List<Edge> adjacenciesList;
    private boolean visited;
    private Vertex predecessor;
    private double distance = Double.MAX_VALUE;

    public Vertex(int ID, String name) { //(Int ID, String name)?
        this.ID = ID;
        this.name = name;
        this.adjacenciesList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void addNeighbour(Edge edge) {
        this.adjacenciesList.add(edge);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setID(int ID) {
        this.ID = ID;
    }

    public int getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<Edge> getAdjacenciesList() {
        return adjacenciesList;
    }

    public void setAdjacenciesList(List<Edge> adjacenciesList) {
        this.adjacenciesList = adjacenciesList;
    }

    public boolean isVisited() {
        return visited;
    }

    public void setVisited(boolean visited) {
        this.visited = visited;
    }

    public Vertex getPredecessor() {
        return predecessor;
    }

    public void setPredecessor(Vertex predecessor) {
        this.predecessor = predecessor;
    }

    public double getDistance() {
        return distance;
    }

    public void setDistance(double distance) {
        this.distance = distance;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.name;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Vertex otherVertex) {
        return Double.compare(this.distance, otherVertex.getDistance());
    }
}
```

***Main***

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NumberFormatException, IOException {

        ReadInput graphReader = new ReadInput();
        Graph graph = graphReader.readFromStream();
        Vertex source = graphReader.calculatesSource();
        Vertex destination = graphReader.calcualteDestination();

        //graph.printEdges();    
        //graph.printVertices();

        ShortestPathFinder finder = new ShortestPathFinder();
        Optional<Path> possiblePath = finder.findShortestPath(graph,source,destination);
        if(possiblePath.isPresent() == false) {
            System.out.println("No path found");
        }
        else {
             System.out.println("Shortest path:");
             finder.getPath();
        }
    }
}
```

***ReadInputIn***

```
public class ReadInput {
    Vertex[] vertex = new Vertex[25252];
    final String DELIMITER = ",";
    int indexVertex = 0;

    //public Vertex[] readVertices() throws NumberFormatException, IOException {
    public Graph readFromStream() throws NumberFormatException, IOException {
         Graph graph = new Graph();
         //25252 number of elements in Place.txt file   

        //Delimiter used in CSV file
            String line = "";
            //Create the file reader
            BufferedReader fileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Place.txt"));
            String IDString = null;
            String name = null;
            int ID = 0;
            //Read the file line by line
            while ((line = fileReader.readLine()) != null) 
            {
                //Get all tokens available in line
                String[] tokens = line.split(DELIMITER);
                //for(String token : tokens)
                //{
                     IDString = tokens[0];
                     name = tokens[1];
                     ID = Integer.parseInt(IDString);
                //}
                 vertex[indexVertex] = new Vertex(ID,name);

                 graph.addVertex(ID,name);
                //System.out.println(indexVertex +":" + vertex[indexVertex].getID());
                indexVertex++;
            }
            fileReader.close();
            //return vertex;        
    //}
    //public Edge[] readEdges() throws NumberFormatException, IOException {
        Edge[] edge = new Edge[127807];
        int indexEdge = 0; 
        String line2 = "";
        BufferedReader fileReader2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Road.txt"));
        String valueString = null;
        String vertex1IDName = null;
        String vertex2IDName = null;
        String extra = null;
        float value = 0;
        int vertex1ID = 0;
        int vertex2ID = 0;
        //Read the file line by line
        while ((line2 = fileReader2.readLine()) != null) 
        {
            //Get all tokens available in line
            String[] tokens2 = line2.split(DELIMITER);
            //for(String token1 : tokens2)
            //{
                vertex1IDName = tokens2[0];
                vertex2IDName = tokens2[1];
                valueString = tokens2[2];
                if(tokens2.length - 1 == 3) {
                    extra = tokens2[tokens2.length - 1];
                }
                else {
                    extra = "";
                }
                vertex1ID = Integer.parseInt(vertex1IDName);
                vertex2ID = Integer.parseInt(vertex2IDName);
                value = Float.parseFloat(valueString);

                //graph.addEdge(value, vertex1ID, vertex2ID, extra);

            //}
            //System.out.println("value: "+ value + " vertex1ID:"+ vertex1ID +" vertex2ID:"+ vertex2ID+ " extra:" + extra);
            //if vertex 1 name or vertex 2 name in vertex.getID()
            for(int i = 0; i< indexVertex; i++) {
                if(vertex1ID == vertex[i].getID() || vertex2ID == vertex[i].getID()){
                    for(int j = 0; j< indexVertex; j++) {
                        if(vertex2ID == vertex[j].getID() || vertex1ID == vertex[j].getID())  {
                            //vertex[i].addNeighbour(edge[indexEdge] = new Edge(value,vertex[i],vertex[j],extra));
                            graph.addEdge(value, vertex[i], vertex[j], extra); //newline for constructing graph
                            //System.out.println("Edge added: "+ vertex1ID +" = " + vertex[i].getID() + "   "+ vertex2ID + " = " + vertex[j].getID());
                            indexEdge++;
                        }   
                    }
                }
            }        
        }
        fileReader2.close();
        return graph;
        //return edge;
    }
    public Vertex calcualteDestination() {

        Scanner scanUserInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the Destination Name:");
        String destinationName = scanUserInput.nextLine();
        scanUserInput.close();

         Vertex Destination = new Vertex(0,null);

       for(int i = 0; i<indexVertex; i++) {
           if(destinationName.equals(vertex[i].getName())){
               Destination.setID(vertex[i].getID());
               Destination.setName(vertex[i].getName());    
           }
       } 
        return Destination;
    }

    public Vertex calculatesSource() {
        Scanner scanUserInput = new Scanner(System.in);  
        System.out.println("Enter the Source Name:");
        String sourceName = scanUserInput.nextLine();

        Vertex Source = new Vertex(0, null);

        for(int i = 0; i<indexVertex; i++) {
            if(sourceName.equals(vertex[i].getName())){
                Source.setID(vertex[i].getID());
                Source.setName(vertex[i].getName());    
            }
        }   

        return Source;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have a few suggestions for how you might consider restructuring your code to make it easier to debug:

- You are currently storing shortest path information with the vertex. This is not good design. Better would be to have the information on the graph separate (and immutable - i.e. no setters) from the volatile information on shortest paths.
- You should have a `Graph` class that holds all vertex and edge sets and exposes only methods to interrogate the graph. You should be able unit test that the graph is set up as you expect after input independently of testing the shortest path algorithm
- The path info should be encapsulated within your `ShortestPath` class - there should be no need to expose that outside the class. You should be able to unit test that independently of the code to read graphs
- Most of the logic in your `main` method should be in a separate classes such as `GraphReader` - these should be unit testable

I suggest you make those changes - I'm confident restructuring the code in this way will make the problem much more obvious.

---

Here's a possible design to give you some ideas of what I'm talking about.

```
class Vertex {
    private final int id;
    private final String name;
}

class Edge {
    private final Vertex vertex1;
    private final Vertex vertex2;
    private final double weight;
}

class Graph {
    private final Set<Vertex> vertices;
    private final Set<Edge> edges;

    public void addVertex(int id, String name) {...}
    public void addEdge(int vertex1, int vertex2, double weight) {...}
    public Vertex getVertex(int id) {...}
    public Map<Vertex,Double> getNeighbours(Vertex vertex) {...}
}

class GraphReader {
    public Graph readFromStream(InputStream input) {...}
}

class Path {
    private final List<Vertex> steps;
}
```

This means you can encapsulate the temporary information you need to hold while building the shortest path into a separate class: vertices and edges don't need to hold that information.

```
class ShortestPathFinder {
    private final Graph graph;
    private final Vertex start;
    private final Vertex end;
    private final Map<Vertex,Double> minimumWeightToVertices;
    private final Map<Vertex,Vertex> previousVertex;
    private final Set<Vertex> visited;

    public ShortestPathFinder(Graph graph, int start, int end) {
        this.graph = graph;
        this.start = graph.getVertex(start);
        this.end = graph.getVertex(end);

        ...
    }

    public boolean hasPath() {...}
    public Path getPath() {...}
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    GraphReader graphReader = new Graph();
    Graph graph = graphReader.readFromStream(System.in);
    ShortestPathFinder finder = new ShortestPathFinder(graph, 1, 10);
    if (finder.hasPath())
        System.out.println("Shortest path " + finder.getPath());
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to hint that the graph isn't actually constructed, and that is why I need a Graph class? My idea was that the graph is constructed when I run the addNeighbor() method. If I were to create this new Graph Class I'm not sure how to do it in a different way.

Comment: No the Graph class is just for better separation of responsibility. Encapsulate logic for setting up the graph in a Graph class rather than in the Vertex. By separating your logic out and testing each piece in turn you'll find it massively easier to debug issues. Your `main` method should really just be a few lines of code with all the work done in other classes.

Comment: Thank you for your help so far, I have rearranged my code to be closer to what you outlined. I am still a bit confused as to where my logic is wrong for getting the correct path. Currently I have built a graph, but now I am not sure how to pass that to my `computeShortestPaths` method without rewriting the entire thing.  Any ideas on this or logic errors for getting the shortest path are much appreciated.

Comment: Have you confirmed your code reading the graph in is working? Have you printed the graph after reading to make sure it looks as you expect? It's worth confirming that before debugging the shortest path code.

Comment: I am able to print info using my graph object, so I believe it is working as expected. I am just not sure as to how I implement the graph object into my algorithm without rewriting the entire thing.

Comment: I'll add some more suggestions to the answer to see if it helps.